# Check for multiple strings in a URL using PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to hide a link on my navigation bar on certain pages of my website. I have a system which works for one page, but when I try to add more than one string to the if statement, it does not work. Can anyone offer advice on how to fix this?

Working statement which hides the link on one page:

```
<?php
    $url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    if (strpos($url, 'terms-of-use') !== false) {

    }

    else {
        echo '<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="'. basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) .'" title="Contact Us">Contact Us</a></li>';
    }
?>
```

I have tried adding the following:

```
if (strpos($url, 'terms-of-use', 'case-studies', 'cookie-policy', 'privacy-policy') !== false) {
```

Comment: BTW… instead of *"if … do nothing else do something"*, simply invert the condition: `if (strpos(…) === false) { echo … }`!

Comment: @deceze I tried this and it removed the link on every page, not just the pages in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For checking for multiple values that one string contains, you can use Regex.

Like this:

```
if(preg_match('(foo|bar)', $baz) === 1) { }
```

This will check if `$baz` contains `"foo"` and `"bar"`.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you so much. I will mark this as the Answer in 7 minutes. (I have to wait)

Answer (score 0):

This should work too:

```
$needles = array('terms-of-use', 'case-studies', 'cookie-policy', 'privacy-policy');
foreach($needles as $what) {
    if(($pos = strpos($url, $what)) !==false ) {
        return true;
}
return false;
```

}

Comment: This doesn't work but the concept of what you are trying is exactly what I am trying to do.